How to make password hashing in django project, i am using custom autentication for login?
I want to make password hashing possible for a django project.
views.py for login.
def asset_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('user_id')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    try:
        user = UserTable.objects.get(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.status == 'inactive':
                messages.error(request, 'Your account is inactive.')
                return redirect('asset_login')
            request.session['name'] = user.name
            request.session['role'] =user.role
            if user.role == 'admin':
                return redirect('admin_dashboard')
            elif user.role == 'ciso':
                return redirect('ciso_dashboard')
            elif user.role == 'fnhead':
                return redirect('fnhead_dashboard')
            elif user.role == 'systemadmin':
                return redirect('systemadmin_dashboard')
            elif user.role == 'assetowner':
                return redirect('assetowner_dashboard')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Unknown user position')
                return redirect('asset_login')  # Redirect to clear form and message
    except UserTable.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
        return redirect('asset_login')  # Redirect to clear form and message
return render(request, 'asset.html')

models.py for username and password
class UserTable(models.Model):
sl_num = models.CharField(max_length=100)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
role=models.CharField(max_length=100)
username=models.CharField(max_length=100)
password=models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

I want to  make paasword hasing possible on django project , i am using custom authentication instead of django build in autentication.

Why are you rolling your own authentication? All of the stuff you're showing us could be done with regular Django auth and a custom user model, and probably better. For instance, you don't have an unique constraint on username in your model.

Use django's AbstractBaseUser for hashing utilities.
Implement a custom authentication backend to handle authentication with hashed password.

referring to django documents you may use custom authentication by changing the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in your settings file to writer your own custom authentication, for example
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend


class MyBackend(BaseBackend):
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
    # Check the username/password and return a user.
    ...

then setting the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ["app.backendfolder.MyBackend"].
now when calling authenticate() it will use the custom method you wrote.
